# DOM with &nbsp; to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, screenshot

I'm trying the example from MDN in which an HTML snippet is drawn to a canvas.
https://jsfiddle.net/c5xrkgL3/

However I added a &nbsp; in the 'like' word and now it doesn't work anymore.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
          '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
          '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
            '<em>I</em> li&nbsp;ke ' +
            '<span style="color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;">' +
            'cheese</span>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</foreignObject>' +
          '</svg>';

data = encodeURIComponent(data);


var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  console.log(canvas.toDataURL());

  canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    var newImg = document.createElement('img'),
    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    newImg.onload = function() {
      // no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };

    newImg.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(newImg);
  });
}

img.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + data
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c5xrkgL3/1/

Any idea what I should do in order to make the &nbsp; example work (while keeping the actual &nbsp; in there)?

Original MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is [not a valid XML entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

There are only 5 valid XML entities

- `&quot;`
- `&amp;`
- `&apos;`
- `&lt;`
- `&gt;`

HTML has a much longer list of valid entities which is where you've got `&nbsp` from but you aren't using a HTML document.

Instead of `&nbsp;` you'll need to use `&#160;` e.g. `li&#160;ke` or as markup: li ke